# Хостер не отвечает

Tags: хостинг

Добрый день. Возникла немного не стандартная проблема.

Ко мне обратился человек который хостится на seo-host.ru с жалобами на недоступность сайта. Собственно оплачивался хостинг стабильно, работал тоже сносно (по крайней мере хозяина сайта все устраивало), раньше... Нынче же постоянно сайт падает в даун. Было решено менять хостера.

А теперь собственно к сути вопроса:

- У хостера нету контактов на сайте -
     ВООБЩЕ
- Хостер не отвечает на почту
     (когда то контакты были, и был найден
     адрес в почте)
- Дампы сайта снять
     смогли - перебрав все их сервера,
     т.е. хостер менял сервер на котором
     находится сайт но не извещал об этом.
- Субдоменами можно управлять из cPanel, основным доменом - нет
- Домен так же регистрировался через этого хостера

Т.е. как достучаться до хостера? Необходимо переносить домены и работать над продвижением сайта но используя этот хостинг нормально сделать это не получится.

UPD. Как оказалось seo-host.ru арендуют сервер/сервера у hostvds.net (p.s. сайт у них тоже работает очень криво, получилось зайти только вот сюда: [hostvds.net/contacts.php] 
[1](http://hostvds.net/contacts.php) ). До них получилось дозвониться и пообщаться. Попросили выслать письмо с полным описанием ситуации, обещались его переслать в seo-host.ru.

Собственно возникает вопрос, если искомый хостер будет и дальше игнорировать наши попытки связаться с ним, какие возможны действия с нашей стороны?

Comment: @ZekMan, рекомендую ознакомиться с [кэшированными версиями](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://seo-host.ru) seo-host за разное время. Может быть, вы найдёте там какие-нибудь другие контакты.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 4):

Всё, что мне удалось выяснить по их IP:

- 01021, Киев, Мечникова, 8, комната 22
- Общие вопросы: noc@hostvds.net
- Жалобы: abuse@hostvds.net
- Вроде бы главный админ: admin@hostvds.net
- Телефон: +380632272446
- Ещё один телефон, вроде Москва: +7 499 5005659
- Ярослав Кравченко

Насколько актуальна информация на сегодняшний день - не знаю.

Comment: >+7499 500659

Позвонил туда, связь плохая, поэтому услышал что-то вроде "Ком фшшшшффшш здравствуйте". Я думаю, что вам стоит туда позвонить, может быть это и правда хостер.

Comment: скорее всего, это координаты дата-центра, где обсуждаемый хостер купил впс или дедик

Answer (score 1):

> У хостера нету контактов на сайте - ВООБЩЕ

Справа снизу "задать вопрос". Учитывая, что судя по описанию они типичные раздолбаи, они вряд ли смотрят почту, думая, что все вопросы будут сыпаться туда.

Comment: Видел, пробовал, почему то уверен что письма падают туда же.